# How i can remove images from PDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf

How i can remove all images from PDF?I want to remove all Images from pdf.

I try to use pdf-lib for it. And do this:

```
         const { PDFDict, PDFDocument, PDFName } = require('pdf-lib');
          const base64String =  window.pdfFile; // here my pdf in base64

          const byteArray = new Uint8Array(atob(base64String).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));

          const arrayBuffer = byteArray.buffer;

          const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'application/pdf' });

          const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(arrayBuffer);

          const firstPage = pdfDoc.getPages()[0];

            const xObjects = firstPage.node
          .Resources()
          .lookup(PDFName.of('XObject'), PDFDict);
      pdfDoc.context.delete(xObjects);

          const pdfDoc2Bytes = await pdfDoc.save();
```

But it doesnt work for me.

Pdf:
https://dropfiles.org/lnJNbZdj

Answer (score 1):

There are challenges in your proposal since editing base64 is highly problematic. Thus the code for **some** image redaction with PDF-Lib 1.0.1 is here https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/issues/124#issuecomment-527462884 (not all PDF images can be done this way).

Basically to remove the PDF image you need to decompress the components and look for a ref to an image  (name and ref can vary) e.g. `/Im1 18 0 R` then once you know that, name you delete that content, then can renumber around the shortage, then re index all the items after the gap. This is not a trivial JS task in binary, but easier as text however redaction is arduous, requiring vasts amount of memory for holding disparate objects while decoded and recompressed.

There are then two further considerations, with respect to fonts, here is result of either method that can then be converted into base64.

File size is now reduced to about 10,760 bytes (that is way more than it's worth as 1KB from scratch would (IMHO) be excessive.)

Without custom font:

[image]

[image]

With custom font:

[image]

Now those results took decades of programming time to get that far, and I don't have decades left, so I would be writing a fastest one line program answer.

```
cmd /r cpdf -draft -draft-remove-only "/Im1" handwritten.pdf 1 -o redacted.pdf && b64 -e redacted.pdf redacted.b64 && type redacted.b64
```

**cpdf is cross platform with a JavaScript API** if you wish to use it that way

Here is the input for then use in JavaScript:

[image]

and once sent as download here is the result:

`cmd /r b64 -d redacted.b64 recovered.pdf && recovered.pdf`

[image]